# Another approach that defines Lebesgue measure.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The statement says that if $\mu'$ is a measure defined on the $\sigma$-algebra  $\Sigma$ of all the Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, s.t. $\mu' \left(a, b \right) = b-a$ for any open interval $ \left(a, b \right)$, then it is indeed Lebesgue measure $\mu$ (which is induced by the Lebesgue outer measure).

I have already shown that for all the open $U\in \Sigma$, $\mu'\left(U\right)=\mu\left(U\right)$. But how to show that $\forall A \in \Sigma$, $\mu'\left(A\right) = \mu \left(A\right)$ in general?

I think there might be a general theorem says that if two measures give the same value on all open sets, then these two measures are the same. Is it true or false?

Comment: It is false, but it becomes true for a fairly general class of measures known as "Radon measures".

Comment: I don't remember the exact details of the proof, but I recall having to show the equivalence for open sets, then for compacts sets, then for arbitrary ones. Hope that helps.

Comment: @GuiseppeNegro: No, it is true in general. First,  note that since we know the measure of intervals,  the measure is locally finite. Furthermore, on the second countable space $\Bbb {R}^d $, every locally finite measure is Radon.